# KSOAP2 - How can I view the xml-code that is being sent?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl, ksoap2

I'm invoking a SOAP webservice using the ksoap2-library. I'm getting the error message "unexpected element" and would now like to see what is actually being sent.

btw., HttpTransport.requestDump doesn't work for some reason.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you set `HttpTransport.debug = true` before making the request? btw you should use `HttpTransportSE` (I don't think that's the problem though).

Comment: Debug was set to "true" (I was using HttpTransportSE, just forgot the "SE").
Although I don't really know what exactly I did, it is now working and I'm getting the xml-output. Thank you very much for your answer anyway!